# Re-write Javascript code into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I write the code below in jQuery and have it apply to all elements w/ class name of `something`. I am trying to get https://gist.github.com/1129073 to apply to multiple elements, specified by class, instead of just a single element, targeted by id.

More specifically, **I'm looking at http://jsfiddle.net/fgnass/9BkjZ/ and trying to make it work on classes instead of just an id, so it can be applied to many elements.**

```
(function(a,b,c){
  setInterval(function(){
    for(
      b=0;
      b<8;c||(a.innerHTML+='<i><b>'),
      a.childNodes[b].style.opacity=(++b-~c)%8*.1+.2);
    c=-~c
  },99)
})(document.getElementsByClassName('something'));
```

The code above only works on the first element w/ class name of `someting` when using `})(document.getElementsByClassName('something')[0]);` as the last line.

Comment: Wow. Where does such a contorted mess as this even come from?

Comment: @MattBall Maybe something like http://www.140byt.es/ ;-)

Comment: ^ Yup lol. ;) @MattBall, see: https://gist.github.com/1129073. I've changed the `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName` because I want it to apply to many `classes` instead of just one `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit of jQuery should do the same thing as your javascript.

```
$('.something').each(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    {
        $(this).append('<b class="b' + i + ' o' + i + '" data-opacity="' + i + '"><i>•</i></b>');
    }
});

setInterval(function() {
    $('.something b').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('o' + $(this).attr('data-opacity'));
        $(this).attr('data-opacity', (parseInt($(this).attr('data-opacity')) + 1) % 8);
        $(this).addClass('o' + $(this).attr('data-opacity'));
    });
}, 99);
```

You may also want to have a look at the following which also create a loading spinner without using an image: 
http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/ 
http://cssload.net/ 
http://www.jquery4u.com/animation/10-css3-jquery-loading-animations-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

it will also work

```
$('.something').show();
```

Comment: Should have been more specific as to what the code is designed to accomplish, please see my updated question above.

Comment: ^ i just laughed my ass off at that jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

To explain a little bit

```
$('.something').fadeIn();
```

taken from SLaks answer

```
$('.something')
```

will grab all the elements with .something class, and fadeIn() is a build-in jquery method which will change the opacity of the element in question from 0 to 1. Please note, if your element has an opacity of 1 and you call fadeIn, I think it will flicker and fade in. There are lots of other jquery utilities other than fadeIn which can be found on jquery website.

```
$('SELECTOR')
```

SELECTOR can be any css selector, for example

```
$('#myID .something')
$('#myID > .something')
$('#myID .something:first-child')
$('div.className #myid')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand the use of CSS selectors in jQuery, but how do I wrap the function inside a class selector target? Please re-read my question to understand what I am trying to accomplish.